# Return all values even if not exist/null

Tags: sql

I am very new to SQL and i am trying to create a simple report.

```
SELECT DNSServer, DNSZone, ClientHostName, ForwardZoneIPAddress, ReverseZoneIPAddress
FROM IPAM.DNSMismatch
where DNSServer = 'DNSSERVERNAME'
```

DNSMismatch https://solarwinds.github.io/OrionSDK/schema/IPAM.DNSMismatch.html

This shows any DNSMismatch as shown below:

```
|DNSServer    |DNSZone  |ClientHostName          |ForwardZoneIPAddress|ReverseZoneIPAddress|
|DNSSERVERNAME|Zone.Com |MisMatchPC.Domain.com   |192.168.1.38        |192.168.1.39    | <-- Mismatch
```

Now the problem is that it doesn't show a record if it the ForwardZone exists but the Reverse doesn't exists/null.

```
|DNSSERVERNAME|Zone.Com |IDoNotExistPC.Domain.com|192.168.1.40 |DOES NOT EXIST/NULL |
```

is there a easy way to show all values even if they are null?

Comment: by "doesn't show a record" you mean the whole row doesn't appear? Or just the NULL field doesn't appear? Because there's nothing in your WHERE clause that would restrict it if the ReverseZoneIPAddress is null. `WHERE ReverseZoneIPAddress IS NOT NULL` would cause the whole row not to be returned when the Reverse address is null, but you haven't specified that in your query.

Comment: You will need to join to the table that holds the DNS Server info. I thought it was `IPAM.DNSServer` but cannot figure out the relationship

Comment: @ADyson The entire record doesn't appear.

Comment: @JohnHC I'll check into it in their documentation, good thinking.

Comment: @Pleb20 in that case there is some more relevant info that you aren't showing/telling us. On the face of it, with no other info, the query should work. If it doesn't, then there are other factors at play which you haven't explained. Therefore it's difficult/impossible to give an accurate answer.

Comment: @ADyson The query I provided works, but it doesn't show any records if for example; ReverseZoneIPAddress doesn't exist while there is a Forward available. as stated in the last code example

Comment: @Pleb20 yes you've already said all of that. It's what you're _not_ saying that must be of significance. On the evidence presented, there is no reason why that SQL should restrict the results in the way you describe. I assume that a record in the table IPAM.DNSMismatch with the fields populated as you've shown (`|DNSSERVERNAME|Zone.Com |IDoNotExistPC.Domain.com|192.168.1.40 |NULL |`) actually does occur??

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?